# The tr function does not translate a word, while the translate function does

Tags: c++, qt, localization, translation

There is such code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QTranslator translator;
    const QString dir = "/usr/share/qt6/translations";

    if (translator.load("qt_ru", dir)) {
        QApplication::installTranslator(&translator);
        qDebug() << QApplication::translate("QShortcut", "Open");
        qDebug() << QApplication::tr("Open");
    }

    ...
}
```

Its output:

```
"Открыть"
"Open"
```

Why isn't the word "Open" translated in the second case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If

```
QApplication::translate("QShortcut", "Open");
```

works, but

```
QApplication::tr("Open");
```

does not, it means "Open" is in the "QShortcut" context. To get that context with `tr()`, write:

```
QShortcut::tr("Open");
```

---

Alternatively, edit translations to put the word in the `QObject` context, so both will find it.

---

Read more: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/i18n-source-translation.html#mark-strings-for-translation

Comment: How can I put the word in the QObject context? Will tr("word") return the translation after that?

Comment: @NameSurname I'm not sure. Look at the .ts file, you see the context there. Then check `lupdate` and related docs on how to set specific context for translations.

Comment: @NameSurname `tr` is static method. You can call it without specifying the class from code inside a method, in which case the class is implicit (class itself or nearest superclass with the method), but it is still static method. If it doesn't find the translation in its "own" context, it will check the superclass context, ending up at `QObject` before giving up if no translation is found.